# MySQL - If data doesn't exits on other database code fails

Tags: mysql

I have small problem. If `items.extra_data` record with item id doesn't exits my C# code skip that but I want if it doesn't exit it returns nothing. How I can do that?

```
SELECT 
  items.Id,
  items.base_item,
  items_extra_data.extra_data 
FROM
  items 
  JOIN items_extra_data 
    ON items_extra_data.item_id = items.Id 
WHERE room_id = 0 
  AND user_id = " + this.Id
```

Comment: Would that be a left join ?

Comment: What C# code? There's just SQL here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the keyword **`LEFT`** prior to the **`JOIN`** keyword. The query will perform an "outer join" operation.

Meaning the query will return rows from **`items`** when a matching row doesn't exist in **`items_extra_data`**, any references to columns from **`items_extra_data`** will return NULL values.